# How to sort tag clouds alphabetically in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a new **"Zone" tag** through the WordPress admin, it should be at the very end, since the **letter Z** is the last in the alphabet. But my tag **"Zone"** is displayed on the page at the very beginning of the list in the tag cloud.

**My code for displaying tags:**

```js
<article class="Tags_Main_Block"> 
 <p class="tag-titles">Tags Cloud:</p>
 <div class="opase">
 
 <?php 
 wp_tag_cloud( [
    'smallest'  => 14,
    'largest'   => 14,
    'unit'      => 'pt',
    'number'    => 0,
    'format'    => 'flat',
    'separator' => "",
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'exclude'   => null,
    'include'   => null,
    'link'      => 'view',
    'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
    'echo'      => true,
    'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',  
] );
?>
 
</div>
 </article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use `wp_tag_cloud()` to get the tags associated with the post. Then, pass in a few parameters. First, the `'format'` parameter makes the tags into an array so we can loop through them. then, we set it to not echo as we want to save it into a variable. You would then need to use the `asort()` function. This is a function inside of PHP, so it isn't exclusive to WordPress.

Here is more parameters that can be passed into the function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_tag_cloud/

```
$tagsExample = wp_tag_cloud(
    ['format' => 'array',
        'echo' => false
    ]); 
    
asort($tagsExample);

foreach($tagsExample as $tag) {
    echo $tag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the asort function automatically sorts an array in alphabetical order?

Comment: or the array itself sorts the values ​​in alphabetical order?

Comment: @alderman - Anytime! Always happy to help! `asort()` sorts an array in ascending order by default. Here are the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: what exactly in your code sorted the array alphabetically?

Comment: @alderman - This PHP function `asort()`